# How to generate total kinetic energy and total potential energy of the generated particles in c++ code?

Tags: c++

I need a program that will generate 100 random particle positions (x,y,and z) and the generates random velocities then takes those velocities and finds the total kinetic energy and total potential energy.

The equation of potential is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pyJL.png).

I am stuck on how to get the total kinetic energy and total potential energy
This is what I have so far and it will generate the positions and velocities.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
 {
     int q, x, y, z, Q, x1, y1, z1;
     printf("Enter the number of particles: \n");
     scanf("%d", &q);
     srand(time(NULL));
     printf("The positions of the particles are:\n x: y: z:\n");
     for (int i=0; i<= q; i++)
     {
         int x=rand()%100;
         int y=rand()%100;
         int z=rand()%100;
         printf("%d %d %d \n", x, y, z);
     }
     printf("Enter number of velocities: \n");
     scanf("%d", &Q);
     srand(time(NULL));
     printf("The velocities are:\n x1: y1: z1:\n");
     for (int i=1; i<=Q; i++)
     {
         while (true)
         {
             x1=rand()%225;
             y1=rand()%225;
             z1=rand()%225;
             if(((x1*x1)+(y1*y1)+(z1*z1))<= 225)
                break;
         }
         cout<<x1<<"\t"<<y1<<"\t"<<z1<<endl;
     }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have potential energy without an external force and a frame of reference.

Comment: How would you find the these without C++ with pen and paper?

Comment: This is definitely more suited for a physics forum rather than SO, as the question is about the algorithm than the code itself.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Ditto for Kinetic Energy although a common thing to do is to compute the minimum value.

Comment: I know how to find the kinetic and potential energy I need help CODING it thank you.

Comment: I applaud the effort to use stack snippets, but those are only for HTML/CSS/Javascript stuff. You can include a link to e.g. https://godbolt.org with your code if you want to provide additional convenience to readers (but still include the code in the question).

Comment: Please describe the algorithm.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to store the particles and their velocities in some kind of container? (e.g. array, `std::array`, or `std::vector`) Wouldn't it make sense that number of particle positions does match the number of velocities? May be, it's stupid by me to think that there should be one velocity vector assigned to each particle...

Comment: Btw. repeating calls of `srand()` are usually a bad idea. Actually, this makes the (pseudo) random values even less random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need a [frame of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame_of_reference). To make things simple we will take the earth. You can however take other frames of reference (for example a particle or a plane) but in that case the formulas below will not be correct! It would be more complex.

The potential energy is calculated relative to a force. We will take the gravity of the earth. You could however calculate potential energy for electrostatic forces, linear springs or even between particles (for example, if your particles were planets then the potential energy of gravitational forces between planets would not be negligible).

We also suppose the the earth is flat. That is the altitude of the particle is given by *z*.

Then the [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) of a particle would be given by

[image]

where *m* is the mass and *v* the velocity. For one particule, you can calculate *v* like that:

```
v = sqrt(pow(x1, 2.0) + pow(x2, 2.0) + pow(x3, 2.0))
```

and the [potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) by

[image]

where *m* is the mass of the particule, *g* is the gravitational acceleration and *h* is the altitude (*z* in your case).

Comment: Each time `pow` is used to square a number, a fairy dies. Personally I wouldn't rely on a compiler to optimise.

Answer (score 1):

This example will be done in literate programming style.

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/particle-energies-58289664
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
```

Let's use 32-bit floating point numbers as our "reals":

```
using real = float;
```

We'll use domain-specific data types: one representing a 3D vector, and another a particle that has a state represented by its position and velocity vectors.

```
struct Vector { 
    real x, y, z;
    constexpr real len() const {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    }
    constexpr Vector operator-(const Vector &o) const {
        return {x-o.x, y-o.y, z-o.z};
    }
};

struct Particle {
    Vector pos, vel;
};
```

The distance between two particles is the length of a vector that is the difference of their positions.

```
constexpr static real distance(const Particle &a, const Particle &b) {
    return (b.pos - a.pos).len();
}
```

The potential difference between a pair of particles is calculated according to the [formula given in the problem assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming).

```
real potential_diff(const Particle &a, const Particle &b) {
    constexpr real A = 2.0f, B = 3.0f, C = 12.0f;
    const real d = distance(a, b);
    const real d6 = d*d*d*d*d*d;
    const real d12 = d6*d6;
    // As d decreases, the higher the power, the sooner it will round to zero.
    return
        (d12 != 0.f) ? A/d12 - B/d6 + C/d :
        (d6 != 0.f) ? -B/d6 + C/d :
        (d != 0.f) ? C/d : 0.f;
}
```

The entire system consists of a number of particles. As an optimization, we also store the potential differences from any particle to all the other particles, i.e. for each particle in the `particles` field, there's a corresponding real in the `potential_diffs`. This is done so that the potential differences that start at each particle can be calculated in parallel.

```
struct System {
    using particle_storage = std::vector<Particle>;
    using const_particle_iterator = particle_storage::const_iterator;
    particle_storage particles;
    std::vector<real> potential_diffs;
```

We now create a functor that calculates the potential energy on a range of particles. The range is given by the pair of iterators. To construct a new calculator we can use aggregate initialization, i.e. `PotentialEnergyCalculator{start, end}` creates a new calculator functor whose result is the sum of potential energy differences between the particle pointed to by `start` and all the other particles between `start` and `end` (end itself is excluded). The calculator is a functor, i.e. you can call it, i.e. `PotentialEnergyCalculator{start,end}()` and this provides the value. We use a functor so that we can easily parallelize the computations for different `start` particles.

```
    struct PotentialEnergyCalculator {
        const_particle_iterator const cbegin, cend;
        real operator()() const
```

The vector of potential differences for each pair of particles in the given calculator is stored in a thread-local vector, since only one calculator can be active at a given time in a given thread. That vector is thus automatically reused, to avoid the costs of reallocating it.

Why do we store the potential differences in a vector, and not immediately sum them? To minimize numerical errors. Collecting them in the vector lets us sort them in ascending order (they are all greater than zero!), and start adding the smallest values first. Consider what happens when you'd add `1E20 + 1E-20 + 1E-20 +...`: the `1E-20` values are too small to fit into a `real` that stores `1E20`, and they lose all of their precision: it doesn't matter how many times we add `1E-20` to `1E20`: it won't have any effect.

```
            thread_local static std::vector<real> potential_diffs;
            potential_diffs.resize(0);
            // calculate potential differences from this particle to those after it
            for (auto ip2 = std::next(cbegin); ip2 != cend; ++ip2)
                potential_diffs.push_back(potential_diff(*cbegin, *ip2));
            // sort the potential differences in ascending order
            std::sort(potential_diffs.begin(), potential_diffs.end());
```

`std::accumulate` guarantees the order of additions, and given that we sorted the differences, they'll be accumulated from least to greatest, without undue loss of precision (precision loss in floating point operations is a tricky topic, but order of addition is a basic issue).

```
            // add potential differences - in ascending order for stability
            return std::accumulate(potential_diffs.cbegin(), potential_diffs.cend(), 0.f);
        }
    };
```

Now we need a method that will calculate the total potential energy in the system. We would like to leverage parallel processing (why not - it's so easy in modern C++!), and the `policy` argument specifies whether to run the computations on the calling thread (i.e. without parallelization) - that's the default `deferred` value, or we could parallelize by providing `std::launch::async` instead.

```
    real calculate_potential_energy(std::launch policy = std::launch::deferred) {
        // obtain potential differences for all particles
```

The results of the calculation "radiating from" each particle are represented by a `std::future`: it's an object that is a handle to a result that may be potentially available in future. The `get()` method forces a future to be evaluated, i.e. it will wait until the value of the future is computed, and then return that value.

```
        std::vector<std::future<real>> potential_diff_futures;
        potential_diff_futures.reserve(particles.size());
```

For every particle pointed to by `ip1`, we compute the sum over `ip1..particles.cend`. For 4 particles, the ranges would be:

```
                 Particle -> 0    1    2    3

potential_diff_futures[0]   REF   *    *    *
potential_diff_futures[1]        REF   *    *
potential_diff_futures[2]             REF   *
potential_diff_futures[3]                  REF
```

There is a `PotentialEnergyCalculator` for each row of the table above, `REF` is the particle used as a reference from computation (the "from" particle), and `*` denote the particles included in the row (sum).

```
        for (auto ip1 = particles.cbegin(); ip1 != particles.cend(); ++ip1) {
            potential_diff_futures.emplace_back(std::async([ip1, ip2 = particles.cend()]{ 
                return PotentialEnergyCalculator{ip1, ip2}(); 
            }));
        }
```

Now we got the futures for all the potential differences, so we need to resolve them, i.e. obtain their results. We put those into the `potential_diffs` vector:

```
        potential_diffs.resize(0);
        potential_diffs.reserve(particles.size());
        for (auto &f : potential_diff_futures)
            potential_diffs.push_back(f.get());
```

And again we sort and accumulate:

```
        // arrange in ascending order
        std::sort(potential_diffs.begin(), potential_diffs.end());
        // add potiential differences - in ascending order for stability
        return std::accumulate(potential_diffs.cbegin(), potential_diffs.cend(), 0.f);
    }
};
```

Let's write a little test harness to ensure that all this works:

```
void test(bool diagn) {
    System sys;
    sys.particles.resize(3);
    auto &ps = sys.particles;
    ps[0].pos = {1,0,0};
    ps[1].pos = {1,1,0};
    ps[2].pos = {0,0,1};
    real const p_dst01 = distance(ps[0], ps[1]);
    real const p_dst02 = distance(ps[0], ps[2]);
    real const p_dst12 = distance(ps[1], ps[2]);
    if (diagn)
        std::cout << "dst01=" << p_dst01 << " dst02=" << p_dst02 << " dst12=" << p_dst12 << std::endl;
    assert(p_dst01 == 1.f);
    assert(p_dst02 == sqrtf(2.f));
    assert(p_dst12 == sqrtf(3.f));
    real const p_en01 = potential_diff(ps[0], ps[1]);
    real const p_en02 = potential_diff(ps[0], ps[2]);
    real const p_en12 = potential_diff(ps[1], ps[2]);
    real const p_sum = p_en12 + p_en02 + p_en01;

    real const p_en = sys.calculate_potential_energy();

    if (diagn)
        std::cout 
            << "en01=" << p_en01 << " en02=" << p_en02 << " en12=" << p_en12
            << "\nen_sum=" << p_sum << " en=" << p_en << std::endl;
    assert(p_sum == p_en);
}

int main()
{
    test(false);
}
```

Generating the random values would be best done with a generating functor passed to `std::generate`, and adding kinetic energy to the total is as simple as adding a `real kinetic_energy(const Particle &)` function, and changing the inner loop to use it:

```
            potential_diffs.push-back(kinetic_energy(cbegin));
            for (auto ip2 = std::next(cbegin); ip2 != cend; ++ip2)
                potential_diffs.push_back(
                    kinetic_energy(*ip2) + potential_diff(*cbegin, *ip2));
```